# AngularJS use of .run after routing to a new page causes issues

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ngRoute to navigate to different pages from a main login page (let's call it `index.html`). The routing is done on its main js file. I have a problem when I am trying to use a `.run` block in a certain page (named `home.html` and which has the corresponding `home.js`, through which `.run` is being executed) I route to from the main page. Since all the js files are listed in that main `index.html` file, it runs all of them while loading that page. As a result, it also executes the `app.run` , which I only want to execute when loading `home.html`.

It seems that I cannot move the listing of `home.js` from `index.html` to `home.html`, it just does not read it. I am assuming that all the js files of the routed pages must be listed only in the main html file?

So, considering all this, my question is how do I manage to execute `.run` for a page I am routing to, but only to that page and not the main routing page?

Comment: That's how angular works, it's going to run through all the code when loaded.  What are you trying to put in the app.run that you don't want to run right away?

Comment: I am sending user details from the index page to the home page and trying to read those while loading the home page, If the variables with the user details are undefined, I am redirecting to the login page. This is just my simple mechanism for making sure one cannot load internal pages of the app without going through authentication first.

Comment: I also just don't understand why I have to declare the home.js in the index.html ? Why can I not route to home.html, list home.js as a script in there and it would just read it? I tried that but it just won't read the home.js unless it is listed directly in the main routing page.

Comment: App run isn't the right place for that.  It would be easier to hold that information in a service since they're singletons.  That way you can have say a UserService that holds the currently logged in user and you just inject it where ever you need it.

Comment: I actually am using a service to store that information. app.run is being used just to verify that information. Somewhere in my js file I have to call that service right? Where else would that be? I could do it from the main controller of the page, but I want to do that earlier (app.run/app.config) so that the page doesn't even begin to load

Comment: See here https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

Answer (score 1):

App Run will always run when the application starts up. Doing things like restricting access should be handled in the controller or where you define your routing rules.

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec